# Listen for event inside multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom event which I listen to:

```
$(document).on('MyCustomEvent', function(e, data) {

});
```

My problem is that I would like to know when `MyCustomEvent` has fired inside a lot of different functions. I don't want to attach the event handler inside each function, since it doesn't make any sense and will probably override eachother.

What I'm after is something like this:

```
function one(){

    //"when MyCustomEvent is fired, do stuff with the 'data' here"
}

function two(){

    //"when MyCustomEvent is fired, do stuff with the 'data' here"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem with attaching all these functions as event handlers?

```
$(document).on('MyCustomEvent', function(e, data) {
    one(data);
});

$(document).on('MyCustomEvent', function(e, data) {
    two(data);
});
```

You would of course need to change the signatures so that the functions accept `data` as an argument. I have attached the two functions separately because usually attaching handlers in a modular manner like this is the only way to go.

You could also use an event namespace so that you can detach the handlers independently of each other:

```
$(document).on('MyCustomEvent.one', function(e, data) {
    one(data);
});

$(document).on('MyCustomEvent.two', function(e, data) {
    two(data);
});

$(document).trigger('MyCustomEvent'); // both functions are called
$(document).off('MyCustomEvent.one');
$(document).trigger('MyCustomEvent'); // only two() is called
```

Comment: I thought that the second time you bind an event listener it would overwrite the first one. But I guess that's not the case then